# How does packages become available on client in an angular project

Tags: angular, webkit, angular-cli, node-modules

I started an angular project and had to do different things to make packages available on client. I will give you examples for different types of packages:

- `@angular`: It is only listed in the `package.json`.
- `moment`: It is listed in the `package.json` and I had to import it in `angular-cli.json` in the `scripts` section like this `"../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"`,
- `simpl-schema`: It is listed in the `package.json` and I had to add types via dts-gen. Like `@angular` it is neithe included in `angular-cli.json` nor in the `index.html`.

Whats the difference between `moment` and the other two packages? Why do I have to include `moment.js` separately?

Comment: It's all compiled into a single or multiple JS files. There are no packages anymore when the application is deployed to the server or delivered to the browser.

Comment: OK but how does `webpack`(?) know that it has to include `@angular` or why is `moment` not included automatically?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that. I'm not using TS (only Dart)